# Is 栖 pronounced xi or qi as in 两栖？

Tags: pronunciation

I checked several [dictionaries](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%A4%E6%A0%96) it's [liǎng qī].

But it's pronounced xi in this  [video](https://m.baidu.com/sf?pd=video_page&atn=index&nid=9250268136282728228&sign=4611393958587747271&word=%E4%B8%A4%E6%A0%96&oword=%E4%B8%A4%E6%A0%96&title=%E4%B8%A4%E6%A0%96%EF%BC%9A%E8%83%BD%E5%9C%A8%E6%B0%B4%E4%B8%AD%E4%B8%8E%E9%99%86%E4%B8%8A%E7%94%9F%E6%B4%BB%E6%88%96%E6%B4%BB%E5%8A%A8&alr=1&openapi=1&resource_id=5052&frsrcid=5933&baijiahao_id=1652825869546538&sp=0&ext=%7B%22src%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fvd3.bdstatic.com%5C%2Fmda-ke7fskkztud9sis9%5C%2Fv1-cae%5C%2Fmda-ke7fskkztud9sis9.mp4%3Fplaylist%3D%255B%2522hd%2522%252C%2522sc%2522%255D%22%2C%22loc%22%3A%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.internal.video.baidu.com%5C%2F7bfdb2e1822052db496167c32fd46fdc.html%22%2C%22log_loc%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fbaijiahao.baidu.com%5C%2Fs%3Fid%3D1666090050374607410%26wfr%3Dcontent%22%2C%22duration%22%3A%2234%22%2C%22poster%22%3A%22https%253A%252F%252Fbkimg.cdn.bcebos.com%252Fpic%252F7dd98d1001e93901213fcca394a443e736d12f2e385f%22%2C%22source%22%3Anull%2C%22s%22%3A%22bffb477c1406152e04290490c6f78cfd%22%2C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

栖 is the simplified character of 棲

棲 has two different pinyin

> [棲](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/7403/) /qi1/

> 1. (of birds) perch; roost

> 2. dwell; stay; reside; settle

~

> [棲](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/7403/) /xi1/

> [adj] restless; fidgety

[兩棲](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/21494/)  /liang3 qi1 / amphibious; dual-talented; able to work in two different lines

The video use  /xi1/ instead of /qi1/, which doesn't match the dictionary. And base on the context, the dictionary is the correct one here

Comment: No. Not necessarily. 栖 by itself is a legitimate traditional Chinese character.